AI Platform on GCP: persistent "Internal error occurred for the current attempt." errors
Starting about a week ago I have been receiving this error constantly for every job I submit to Google's AI Platform: Internal error occurred for the current attempt.. The error repeats 3 times per job before the job is terminated. I have tried changing the region when using the
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training

command but to no avail. Meanwhile, when I run
gcloud compute regions list

the status of every region is "UP". As it stands the AI Platform is completely unusable to me. What can I do?

Have you tried submitting in another region Ex:gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training --region =us-east1? Please take a look at these link1,link2 and link3?

@kiranmathew I already said in the question I tried switching region. Those links also appear to be for Vertex-AI not AI-Platform, are you sure those are relevant?

Hi @Patrick, this type of error message occurs when there are some internal errors that prevent the restart. To find the root cause of the error you can consider creating a gcp case ticket. You can find more details of the error message by checking the logs.

@kiranmathew You mean using the Logs Explorer? I'm already using that for my job_id - this is the only way to see the "Internal error occurred" message in the first place. Or are more details logged under a separate filter? It seems like I have to pay to get any support here, which is annoying.
